# Extract key from key-value pair

Tags: bash, regex, grep, awk

I have a file looking like that.

```
mke_version          = "3.3.7"
msr_version          = "2.8.5"
mcr_version          = "19.03.14"
```

I want to print from file only key `mke_version` but don't print the value of it.
I've tried something like that:

`grep -Eo "(?<=^mke_version ).*" file`

But it wasn't working cause of this error.

`grep: bad regex '(?<=^mke_version ).*': Repetition not preceded by valid expression`

Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: Strange question, you want to print a key that you know before. I think you want to know if the key is in the file. So you must try something like that : [ "$(grep '^mke_version' file)" ] && echo OK || echo NOK

Comment: @ctac_ I don't need to validate if it's their or not, I already know that it's in the file, and going to be there every time cause of default template generation with `cat <<EOF` I just needed a way to get a key from file without outputting value. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No needs for lookbehind, this does the job:

```
grep -o "^mke_version" file
```

**Output:**

```
mke_version
```

Comment: Thank you. That works for me

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for myself with this command

`grep "^mke_version" file | awk -F"=" '{ print $1 }'`

It's easier to grep for a specific key and print only the first column of it, nothing else needed for me, if you know a way to improve - please comment.

Thanks

Comment: You need not use grep, awk can do regex match `awk -F= '/^mke_version/{print $1}' file`